# Deploy keycloakify jar file for custom theme in docker-compose.yaml file in linux server

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, jboss, keycloak

I have a .jar file generated using keycloakify. I want to deploy a custom theme on linux server. Keycloak is running based on `docker-compose.yaml` file.

I have already moved .jar file to linux server. Now I want to integrate custom theme to keycloak.

What steps needed to follow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, We need to mount the respective Jar file path to keycloak deployment.
We can add the following line to mount the custom theme to the docker container.

```
- /data/test/config/ejectTheme/kcTheme.jar:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/kcTheme.jar
```